# Knitr Getting "Stuck" When Adding Any Code to a R Markdown File

Tags: r, google-drive-api, knitr

Although recently I have been encountering an issue with the Knit function "stalling" as in the output in the consul only makes it through 66% of the first "unnamed code chunk" and never progresses any further ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkt9f.png)).

With the above screen shot I downloaded a .RMD file and it Knit just fine the first time when I just added my name (but no code), but when I add anything for code (as I have in the screenshot) it gets "stuck" and never progresses past what you see in markdown console. (Sorry this screenshot is an example .RMD File I am using from my grad stats class.)

The other week I had this issue with some data and resolved it by changing the folder where the .RMD file was saved and that seemed to fix it that time. Although now I am encountering the issue again and I cannot seem to fix it this time.

The first time it seemed to be due to me storing all my files on google drive which synchronizes with my computer and maybe R struggles with processing the intermediate files? Thus that time once I saved the file to my desktop and directed the output file there it worked. Although I have also tried to save the files all in a folder on my desktop this time and it seems to not resolve the issue.

Has anyone had this issue of knitr stalling indefinitely or know what the root cause may be. This has been happening to all my .RMD files lately (and I have uninstalled and reinstalled r/rstudio).

Cheers!

-Nathan

Comment: I think using the `View` function is causing you issues here, it only works in a "live" R session.

Comment: Yes that was the answer, thank you very much!